# How to handle multi-line results of user-defined functions in polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'd like to parse lines of text to multiple columns and lines in polars, with user defined function.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'file': ['aaa.txt','bbb.txt'], 'text': ['my little pony, your big pony','apple+banana, cake+coke']})

def myfunc(p_str: str) -> list:
    res = []
    for line in p_str.split(','):
        x = line.strip().split(' ')
        res.append({f'word{e+1}': w for e, w in enumerate(x)})
    return res
```

If I just run a test it's fine, list of dicts is created:

```
myfunc(df['text'][0])

[{'word1': 'my', 'word2': 'little', 'word3': 'pony'},
 {'word1': 'your', 'word2': 'big', 'word3': 'pony'}]
```

Even creating a dataframe of it is easy:

```
pl.DataFrame(myfunc(df['text'][0]))
```

But trying to do map_elements() fails:

```
(df.with_columns(pl.struct(['text']).map_elements(lambda x: myfunc(x['text'])).alias('aaa')
                 )
 )
```

thread '' panicked at crates/polars-core/src/chunked_array/builder/list/anonymous.rs:161:69:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidOperation(ErrString("It is not possible to concatenate arrays of different data types."))
--- PyO3 is resuming a panic after fetching a PanicException from Python. ---

What I'd like as a result is something like:

```
file     word1         word2   word3
aaa.txt  my            little  pony
aaa.txt  your          big     pony
bbb.txt  apple+banana
bbb.txt  cake+coke
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely due to the complex return type returned by the UDF. Polars quickly infers the dtype of the inner dictionaries. However, the dictionaries being evaluated later might have a different number of fields and the error is raised.

A simpler reproducible example would be the following.

```py
import random

import polars as pl

def ufunc(x: int):
    return [
        {f"word_{i}": "elephant" for i in range(random.randint(1, 4))}
        for _ in range(random.randint(1, 4))
    ]

pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2]}).with_columns(pl.col("id").map_elements(ufunc))
```

Originally, I thought correctly setting the `returned_dtype` parameter of [`pl.Expr.map_elements`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_elements.html) would resolve the issue. However, I didn't find a way to specify a struct dtype with varying number of fields.

Still, when wrapping the return value into another list, polars seems to infer the returned dtype correctly. Then, we can obtain the first (and only) list element using [`.list.first`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.first.html#polars.Expr.list.first), explode the lines into rows using [`pl.DataFrame.explode`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html), and finally unnest the inner structs.

```py
(
    pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2]})
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("id").map_elements(lambda x: [ufunc(x)]).list.first()
    )
    .explode("id")
    .unnest("id")
)
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ word_0   ┆ word_1   ┆ word_2   ┆ word_3   │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ elephant │
│ elephant ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ elephant ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ elephant ┆ null     │
│ elephant ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null     │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the UDF altogether as follows.

1. Split text into list of lines
2. Expand list of lines into separate rows
3. Strip separate lines and split into list of words
4. Convert list of words into a struct and map the fields to match the pattern `"word_IDX"`

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("text").str.split(",")
    )
    .explode("text")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("text").str.strip_chars().str.split(" ")
        .list.to_struct()
        .name.map_fields(lambda s: s.replace("field_", "word_"))
    )
    .unnest("text")
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────────┬──────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ file    ┆ word_0       ┆ word_1 ┆ word_2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str     ┆ str          ┆ str    ┆ str    │
╞═════════╪══════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ aaa.txt ┆ my           ┆ little ┆ pony   │
│ aaa.txt ┆ your         ┆ big    ┆ pony   │
│ aaa.txt ┆ your         ┆ big    ┆ pony   │
│ bbb.txt ┆ apple+banana ┆ null   ┆ null   │
│ bbb.txt ┆ cake+coke    ┆ null   ┆ null   │
└─────────┴──────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: The functionality implemented by the UDF is just an example, in the original problem it is way more complex. Essentially it is returning a list of dicts, and that is what I'd like to use somehow.

Comment: 'But what I really meant...' is a regular source of frustration for those responding to SO questions. It pays to make questions complete whilst having no irrelevancies.

Comment: @user19077881 what an understatement.